# Easy Oven Cleaning - No products

Tags: substitutions, oven, cleaning

The manual for my oven states that only warm water should be used for cleaning.

I've followed this so far but it is becoming increasingly difficult to keep the oven in a respectable condition.

Does anyone have any experience using natural options such as baking soda and vinegar, with ovens that require 'product free' cleaning?

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned advice, Ben. Would you mind mentioning the make and model number of your oven? Not knowing that won't prevent an answer. But for various reasons, having that information might help facilitate one.

Comment: There's nothing special about baking soda and vinegar. They are as likely (or not likely) to damage your oven as any other cleaning product.

Comment: I will look up the model number now. I was hoping it might be less abrasive and be more of a mechanical process as opposed to chemical.

Answer (score 3):

**Is it a self-cleaning oven?**

If so, running the cleaning cycle according to the instructions should leave nothing but a fine ash on the oven, which is easily removable with just warm water.

Comment: which at this point sounds more likely than not.

Comment: I've never seen a non-self-cleaning oven manual that says to not use cleaning products. That would be, like, a disposable oven.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't a self cleaning oven! The lining is supposed to be 'easy clean' its currently proving otherwise.

Comment: Ahhh! If there's some fancy oven-liner rather than enameled-steel, that's a whole different story...

Comment: especially if functioning as the "belly of a stove" with no discernable(?) make or model number, the manual perhaps penned by Franklin himself.